# Function's multiple ParameterSets work when being declared from a script, but not when being imported from a module

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I wrote a 'wrapper' function for the Send-MailMessage function with a hard-coded `SmtpServer` argument (that's all it does). Here's the header declaring the sets:

```
function SendMessage {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path')]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               ParameterSetName='Path',
               HelpMessage='the path and filename to the message you would like to send')]
    [String]$Path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               HelpMessage="A string containing the message which you want to send",
               ParameterSetName='Msg')]
    [String]$Msg,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, 
               HelpMessage='Your Admin Office 365 credentials',
               ParameterSetName='Path')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               ParameterSetName='Msg')]
    [Alias('Credentials')]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Cred,

    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               HelpMessage='The address to which you want to send the message',
               ParameterSetName='Path')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               ParameterSetName='Msg')]
    [String[]]$To,

    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               HelpMessage='The email from which you want to send the message',
               ParameterSetName='Path')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               ParameterSetName='Msg')]
    [String]$From,

    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               HelpMessage='The subject of the email to send out',
               ParameterSetName='Path')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               ParameterSetName='Msg')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$Subject,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path',
               HelpMessage='[Optional] If you want it cc''d to anyone')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Msg')]
    [String[]]$CC
)
# do function stuff
}
```

The function has two `ParameterSet`s: `Path` and `Msg`.

When I run it as a `.ps1` script, I can see both sets:

```
PS U:\> test.ps1
PS U:\> gcm SendMessage -Syntax

SendMessage -Path <string> -Cred <pscredential> -To <string[]> -From <string> -Subject <string> [-CC <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]

SendMessage -Msg <string> -Cred <pscredential> -To <string[]> -From <string> -Subject <string> [-CC <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

But when I import it as a module, I can only see the `Path` set:

```
PS U:\> Import-Module -Name test.psm1
PS U:\> gcm SendMessage -Syntax

SendMessage [-Cred] <pscredential> [-Path] <string> [-To] <string> [-From] <string> [-Subject] <string> [[-CC] <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]

PS U:\>
```

I would like to be able to import both sets when I import the module.

Is there anything obvious which I am missing?
Thank you.

**EDIT**: I am using PS version 5.1, and have been testing using the ISE.

Comment: What does the export look like in your module?

Comment: Did you export it from the module? When you run `Import-Module` use `-Force` and `-Verbose` and let's see if it's actually coming from there. Also `gcm SendMessage` (no `-Syntax`) and see if the command is coming from the module.

Comment: I'm exporting explicitly with `Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Alias *` at the bottom of the file.

The command is coming from the module, and I have tried both `-Verbose` and `-Force`.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using ? I'm not able to repro this

Comment: I'm using version 5.1

Comment: Make sure you are not testing this with PowerShell_ISE

Comment: I am testing with the ISE

Answer (score 0):

Testing scripts and function with the ISE makes it so complex. variables and functions in ISE is always available in global scope. Test this in PowerShell console.

Open a new PowerShell console, and dot source `test.ps1`

```
. c:\test.ps1
Get-Command SendMessage -Syntax
```

Open another PowerShell console and run `Import-Module`

```
Import-Module c:\Test.ps.1 -Verbose
Get-Command SendMessage -syntax
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I think this was covered by @Jacov Colvin and @briantist's comments above, that is: what could be happening is that the function being tested by `Get-Command` is not necessarily the one I imported, but something else with the same name, if I understood correctly.
In any case, after trying with both `-Force` and `-Verbose` I can confirm that the function exported is the one I want, and that it is coming from the module in question.
I have also attempted your suggestion and tried using the console, not the ISE, and the result was the same, so it's something else..